# set bootstrap admin template for dotnetnuke admin pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, admin, dotnetnuke, skin

How to set admin skin of DOTNETNUKE in such way that all admin pages take that theme?
I want to use one of admin templates of bootstrap 3 but it seems that dotnetnuke admin pages has its own CSS class which does not match bootstrap class.
what should i do?

Comment: I really need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual modules within DNN do have their own styles. Therefore you will not be able to have the actual interactions in those modules use bootstrap styles without making modifications to the core modules

You can set the overall skin on admin pages just like any other page though. The content will be your only item needing work.

Comment: you mean i just need set style for Content Panes and drop modules into them? and there is no way to set style for all admin pages ?

Comment: Sort of...you can set the styles for the overall site.  But the individual modules.  For example "User Accounts" will use their own CSS Classes.  You could look at overrides to try to bring it inline with bootstrap, but it isn't going to bring everything into the bootstrap standard.